# Images in treeview nodes/subnodes

Tags: c#, treeview

I'm using a treeview with this structure

[image]

I have to add an image for every SUB-SUBCHILD that represents tha data type (int, char, etc...) but it works in a strange way...

image1 is the "char" image instead of "int"
image2 is the "char" image
image3 is the "double" image instead of "char"
image4 is the default (index 0) image  instead of "double"

The last SUB-SUBCHILD is alway different than the expected!

In the debug mode the imagelist index value is what I expected to see, but in the treeview no.

Why?

This is my code:

```
    private void createTree(string[,] strArrLF3) //strArrLF3 matrix of n ROWS and 11 COLS
    {
        int counter = 0;
        Int32 arrayLen = 0;

        arrayLen = (strArrLF3.Length) / 11;

        trvSimulations.ImageList = imgListRes;  //trvSimulation is the name of treeview

        TreeNode ParentNode = new TreeNode();
        ParentNode.Text = "Root";
        ParentNode.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        ParentNode.BackColor = Color.White;

        ParentNode.ImageIndex = 0;
        ParentNode.SelectedImageIndex = 0;
        trvSimulations.Nodes.Add(ParentNode);         //Root node

        TreeNode trvChild_ATSM0 = new TreeNode();
        trvChild_ATSM0.Text = "CHILD1";
        trvChild_ATSM0.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        trvChild_ATSM0.BackColor = Color.White;
        trvChild_ATSM0.ImageIndex = 1;
        trvChild_ATSM0.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
        ParentNode.Nodes.Add(trvChild_ATSM0);         //CHILD1 node (child of Root node)

        TreeNode chdIN_ATSM0 = new TreeNode();
        chdIN_ATSM0.Text = "Input Signals";
        chdIN_ATSM0.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        chdIN_ATSM0.BackColor = Color.White;
        chdIN_ATSM0.ImageIndex = 3;
        chdIN_ATSM0.SelectedImageIndex = 3;
        trvChild_ATSM0.Nodes.Add(chdIN_ATSM0);         //Input node (child of  CHILD1)

        TreeNode chdOUT_ATSM0 = new TreeNode();
        chdOUT_ATSM0.Text = "Output Signals";
        chdOUT_ATSM0.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        chdOUT_ATSM0.BackColor = Color.White;
        chdOUT_ATSM0.ImageIndex = 2;
        chdOUT_ATSM0.SelectedImageIndex = 2;
        trvChild_ATSM0.Nodes.Add(chdOUT_ATSM0);         //Output node (child of  CHILD1)

        TreeNode sub_chdIN_ATSM0 = new TreeNode(), sub_chdOUT_ATSM0 = new TreeNode();

        counter = 0;
        int imagePos = 0;
        for (counter = 0; counter < arrayLen; counter++)
        {
            string signal = strArrLF3[counter, 9]; //matrix column containing a string ("int", "char", "long", "double")
            imagePos = imageSigType(signal);  //function containing a SWITCH/CASE that return an integer value (index of imagelist) 
            if (strArrLF3[counter, 0] == "CHILD1")
            {
                if (strArrLF3[counter, 8] == "I")
                {
                    sub_chdIN_ATSM0.ImageIndex = imagePos;
                    sub_chdIN_ATSM0.SelectedImageIndex = imagePos;
                    sub_chdIN_ATSM0 = chdIN_ATSM0.Nodes.Add(strArrLF3[counter, 1]);
                }
                else if (strArrLF3[counter, 8] == "O")
                {
                    sub_chdOUT_ATSM0.ImageIndex = imagePos;
                    sub_chdOUT_ATSM0.SelectedImageIndex = imagePos;
                    sub_chdOUT_ATSM0 = chdOUT_ATSM0.Nodes.Add(strArrLF3[counter, 1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: This can be trivially explained by your ImageLists not being correctly initialized.

Comment: @HansPassant Which is the correct way to initialise an ImageList?

Comment: Add the images in the right order so that the hard-coded indexes you use in your code match the correct image.  Or use ImageKey and SelectedImageKey instead so you don't have to hard-code numbers.

Comment: @HansPassant The images are in the right order in the ImageList. I've tried using one line of code `sub_chdIN_ATSM0 = chdIN_ATSM0.Nodes.Add(null,strArrLF3[counter, 1],imagePos,imagePos);` and seems to be ok, now...